# how to get document.referer with angular 2 dart?

Tags: dart

We can have the referrer with javascript by using document.referrer. But what about angular 2 dart?
The Document does not have this option and I couldn't find it within Angular 2.
Any ideas?
I will use interop if no official way around.

EDIT: the html.document does have the referrer property, however, the html.window.document is a whole different object, and thats why I couldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document` does have the `referrer` property:

```
import 'dart:html'; 

main() {
  print(document.referrer);
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5dabda72d1f445a6a62d366455b3f05f)

Comment: Thanks. I tried window.document.referrer, but it seems that the html.document is a different object.

Comment: Actually `window.document.referrer` works as well, but the analyzer complains about `window.document.referrer` because `window.document` has a return type `Document` while `document` is defined as type `HtmlDocument`, but `window.document` returns also a `HtmlDocument` therefore `(window.document as HtmlDocument).referrer` would get rid of the analyser warning.